# How to buy GNT tokens using myetherwallet

Tags: ether, tokens, exchanges, myetherwallet, erc-20

this is my first time buying Ethereum tokens on mainnet. Probably I am doing something wrong, so I am willing to hear any comments or hints about this process. My ethereum address on mainnet is https://etherscan.io/address/0x919ae3010329decba980259d1e624be6028d16c7

Through https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts I tried to call TokenSeller contract https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/TokenSeller-And-TokenSellerFactory as described at https://cryptoderivatives.market/token/GNT

I am just interested in buying a few Golem Network Tokens (GNT), basically spending 0.1 ethers just to test around. So I executed the method createSaleContract() on contractAddress 0xb1eb96f752c624dc784d80961a1accfaf348c923 and ABI:

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"tokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerWithdrawERC20Token","outputs":[{"name":"ok","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"tradeContract","type":"address"}],"name":"verify","outputs":[{"name":"valid","type":"bool"},{"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"sellPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"units","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"name":"sellPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"units","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"name":"createSaleContract","outputs":[{"name":"seller","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"payable":false,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"ownerAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"tokenSellerAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"asset","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sellPrice","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"units","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sellsTokens","type":"bool"}],"name":"TradeListing","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"tokenAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"OwnerWithdrewERC20Token","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"}]
```

the call parameters are:

```
asset Golem => 0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d
sellPrice .1
units 40 => rate .0025
sellsTokens true
```

the resulting transaction is:

tx:

```
amount 0
gas limit 29091
```

raw tx:

```
{"nonce":"0x00","gasPrice":"0x098bca5a00","gasLimit":"0x71a3","to":"0xb1eb96f752c624dc784d80961a1accfaf348c923","value":"0x00","data":"0xc5e412e5000000000000000000000000a74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","chainId":1}
```

Transaction submitted: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6f739b16584e8e9d24ee34c79efbd60463da8cb6c3f05fdca74c6e400d5b0867

But got this error:

```
     Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]
```

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying GNT's through https://cryptoderivatives.market/token/GNT only requires the buyer to send ethers to the contract address and the GNTs will be sent back to the buyers account.

In the following screen, I've selected the cheapest GNT TokenTrader contract line currently and the address [0x6c50aa6b45d3713b93efa009a8e2060911abffd2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c50aa6b45d3713b93efa009a8e2060911abffd2) is highlighted in the **Address** field:

[image]

All you need to do to buy from this contract is to use the https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction **Send Ether & Tokens** tab specifying the contract **Address** as the **To Address** and the amount of ethers to send in the **Amount to Send** field:

[image]

Following is a sample transaction sending funds to that address to receive GNTs - [0xd92d8170...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd92d8170903aaa56435412b8741bf40091c2c2a483dc66792cde3b076c9a050e). In this case 198.5 GNTs were sent back to the account that sent 0.4764 ETH to the contract.

[image]

Just search for the cheapest GNT token when you are ready to try your trade.

Comment: Thx a lot! Now I've got GNTs!

Answer (score 0):

You can buy GNT easily from https://liqui.io/
but you need btc not eth
it's small exchange but the only one.